# My Kodicom 4400R Camera cards are not working after upgrading to 20.04LTS server

Tags: drivers, kernel, video, v4l, video-capture-card

These cards were working under a 16.04 server but that server died so I built up a new box running 20.04 and, when I install the cards, they don't work.

I was trying to view the camera with zoneminder but I had no luck.  To troubleshoot the issue, I deleted the monitor in zoneminder (to ensure the device isn't being used), downloaded v4l-utils*, built v4l2grab and when I ran it, the saved files contain no images.

*I cloned the v4l-utils repo, cd to v4l-utils, checked out v4l-utils-1.18.0 (the version that is used by 20.04LTS), ran make (no errors), cd to contrib/test and ran ./v4l2grab with no arguments.

Here's the dmesg output from the time I first tried running
v4l2grab since the system booted (there's more in dmesg between boot time and here but I can't post it now.

```
[17648.566238] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[17648.566254] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 2760 at drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-ioctl.c:1069 v4l_querycap+0x8f/0xa0 [videodev]
[17648.566255] Modules linked in: ip6table_filter ip6_tables xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_filter bpfilter bttv coretemp tea575x tveeprom kvm_intel videobuf_dma_sg videobuf_core kvm rc_core videodev mc input_leds wmi_bmof mei_me mei mac_hid sch_fq_codel dm_multipath msr scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_generic i915 gpio_ich i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops usbhid lpc_ich drm e1000e pata_acpi hid ahci i2c_i801 libahci wmi video floppy
[17648.566284] CPU: 1 PID: 2760 Comm: v4l2grab Tainted: G        W         5.4.0-84-generic #94-Ubuntu
[17648.566285] Hardware name: LENOVO 7373RK3/LENOVO, BIOS 5CKT51AUS 07/23/2009
[17648.566290] RIP: 0010:v4l_querycap+0x8f/0xa0 [videodev]
[17648.566292] Code: 00 00 80 48 b9 00 00 20 00 00 00 20 00 48 0b 4b 54 21 d6 39 f2 75 13 48 89 4b 54 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 0f 0b eb d0 <0f> 0b 48 89 4b 54 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 66 66 66 66 90
[17648.566293] RSP: 0018:ffff99b50080fc68 EFLAGS: 00010206
[17648.566294] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff99b50080fd88 RCX: 0521000585200015
[17648.566295] RDX: 0000000085010005 RSI: 0000000085000005 RDI: ffff99b50080fdc8
[17648.566296] RBP: ffff99b50080fc90 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000000000c
[17648.566297] R10: ffff99b50080fdd8 R11: ffff99b60080fdbb R12: ffff8a8349910870
[17648.566298] R13: ffff8a834a525800 R14: ffff8a8349943800 R15: ffffffffc099a6c0
[17648.566299] FS:  00007ff4345cbb80(0000) GS:ffff8a838a300000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[17648.566300] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[17648.566301] CR2: 00007ff434a5bfe0 CR3: 00000000cb400000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
[17648.566302] Call Trace:
[17648.566310]  __video_do_ioctl+0x1a7/0x410 [videodev]
[17648.566313]  ? list_lru_add+0x6c/0x1c0
[17648.566319]  ? v4l_s_fmt+0x670/0x670 [videodev]
[17648.566324]  video_usercopy+0x300/0x700 [videodev]
[17648.566327]  ? path_openat+0x140/0x290
[17648.566333]  video_ioctl2+0x15/0x20 [videodev]
[17648.566337]  v4l2_ioctl+0x4c/0x60 [videodev]
[17648.566339]  do_vfs_ioctl+0x407/0x670
[17648.566341]  ksys_ioctl+0x67/0x90
[17648.566343]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x1a/0x20
[17648.566345]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
[17648.566348]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[17648.566349] RIP: 0033:0x7ff43494a89d
[17648.566351] Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d c3 f5 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[17648.566352] RSP: 002b:00007ffeccf5f268 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
[17648.566353] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000280 RCX: 00007ff43494a89d
[17648.566354] RDX: 00007ffeccf5f2c0 RSI: 0000000080685600 RDI: 0000000000000003
[17648.566355] RBP: 00007ffeccf5f400 R08: 00007ffeccf5ec70 R09: 00007ffeccf5f330
[17648.566356] R10: 000000000000000a R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000003
[17648.566357] R13: 00007ffeccf5f330 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[17648.566358] ---[ end trace f7f2411a3d979c0f ]---
[17648.566422] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[17648.566428] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 2760 at drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-ioctl.c:1069 v4l_querycap+0x8f/0xa0 [videodev]
[17648.566429] Modules linked in: ip6table_filter ip6_tables xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_filter bpfilter bttv coretemp tea575x tveeprom kvm_intel videobuf_dma_sg videobuf_core kvm rc_core videodev mc input_leds wmi_bmof mei_me mei mac_hid sch_fq_codel dm_multipath msr scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_generic i915 gpio_ich i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops usbhid lpc_ich drm e1000e pata_acpi hid ahci i2c_i801 libahci wmi video floppy
[17648.566450] CPU: 1 PID: 2760 Comm: v4l2grab Tainted: G        W         5.4.0-84-generic #94-Ubuntu
[17648.566450] Hardware name: LENOVO 7373RK3/LENOVO, BIOS 5CKT51AUS 07/23/2009
[17648.566456] RIP: 0010:v4l_querycap+0x8f/0xa0 [videodev]
[17648.566457] Code: 00 00 80 48 b9 00 00 20 00 00 00 20 00 48 0b 4b 54 21 d6 39 f2 75 13 48 89 4b 54 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 0f 0b eb d0 <0f> 0b 48 89 4b 54 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 66 66 66 66 90
[17648.566458] RSP: 0018:ffff99b50080fc68 EFLAGS: 00010206
[17648.566459] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff99b50080fd88 RCX: 0521000585200015
[17648.566460] RDX: 0000000085010005 RSI: 0000000085000005 RDI: ffff99b50080fdc8
[17648.566461] RBP: ffff99b50080fc90 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000000000c
[17648.566462] R10: ffff99b50080fdd8 R11: ffff99b60080fdbb R12: ffff8a8349910870
[17648.566463] R13: ffff8a834a525800 R14: ffff8a8349943800 R15: ffffffffc099a6c0
[17648.566464] FS:  00007ff4345cbb80(0000) GS:ffff8a838a300000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[17648.566465] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[17648.566466] CR2: 00007ff4347ca294 CR3: 00000000cb400000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
[17648.566467] Call Trace:
[17648.566472]  __video_do_ioctl+0x1a7/0x410 [videodev]
[17648.566474]  ? alloc_set_pte+0x118/0x610
[17648.566477]  ? filemap_map_pages+0x24c/0x380
[17648.566482]  ? v4l_s_fmt+0x670/0x670 [videodev]
[17648.566487]  video_usercopy+0x300/0x700 [videodev]
[17648.566493]  video_ioctl2+0x15/0x20 [videodev]
[17648.566498]  v4l2_ioctl+0x4c/0x60 [videodev]
[17648.566499]  do_vfs_ioctl+0x407/0x670
[17648.566502]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x216/0x450
[17648.566503]  ksys_ioctl+0x67/0x90
[17648.566505]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x1a/0x20
[17648.566507]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
[17648.566508]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[17648.566509] RIP: 0033:0x7ff43494a89d
[17648.566510] Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d c3 f5 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[17648.566511] RSP: 002b:00007ffeccf5f168 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
[17648.566513] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ff4347ca280 RCX: 00007ff43494a89d
[17648.566514] RDX: 00007ffeccf5f1d0 RSI: 0000000080685600 RDI: 0000000000000003
[17648.566514] RBP: 00007ffeccf5f1a0 R08: 00007ffeccf5f330 R09: 00007ffeccf5f330
[17648.566515] R10: 00007ffeccf5f330 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000011
[17648.566516] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00007ffeccf5f1d0 R15: 000056550a31a5d0
[17648.566518] ---[ end trace f7f2411a3d979c10 ]---
```

It looks like something in the v4l driver is crashing but I don't have enough knowledge to troubleshoot the issue myself.

Please let me know if I should post more information such as

- more from dmesg
- modinfo bttv
- systool -vm bttv
- v4l-info lspci
- scanpci.gatos

or whatever else.  I'll be keeping a close eye on this question for a bit.

Comment: You weren't specific as to what 20.04 product you're talking about (desktop? server? but mentioned 16.04 server then only 20.04) nor which kernel stack you opted to use (LTS releases come with two options), but esp. given it's an old card you want to use, did you use the GA kernel stack? (*I tend to find the older kernel stack better for older hardware as a general rule*)  Being specific with details allows us to be more precise; but I don't know what you're using, so the only link I can provide is generic - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: 20.04LTS Server: 
$ uname -a
Linux camserver 5.4.0-84-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 20:27:37 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @guiverc
Are you suggesting I try the following command?
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04
What happens then?

Comment: That would install the HWE stack and give you the option of the GA (5.4) kernel or HWE (currently 5.11) kernel to choose from, thus having different kernel modules (ie. *drivers*) available. However my suggestion was if you were using the HWE, the GA may better help you - you're already on GA; so it may not help - but key it may help anyway. The effect is just extra packages (you select kernel at `grub` and you can remove on stack if you so wish as per wiki page). Ubuntu Desktop defaults to HWE, Ubuntu Server to GA - you were already on GA which is what I suggest trying.

Comment: So the gist of what you are saying is that, because I am already on GA, which is already the older kernel, upgrading to an HWE kernel may or may not help me but I should try.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled everything on a new box and now the cards are working.  Go figure.